# How to search a source file for two specific functions which take the same argument?

Tags: shell, full-text-search

I have a large source code tree in C, and i am interesting in searching the source files for occurences of calls to two specific functions, sin() and cos(), with the same argument being passed to the two functions.
A few examples:

```
double t = sin(1.2) + cos(1.2); //match

y = sin ( x/a ); //match
z = cos(x  /  a  );

j = sin(x) + cos(y); //no match

if (something) {
  x = sin(x); // match
  y = cos(x);
}

if (something)
  x = sin(x); //no match!!! This is a tough case...
else
  y = cos(x)
```

So the question is: how to implement a program/script which can run on a typical Linux shell which will search for what is described above?

Comment: it's highly unlikely you'll find a tool that's able to do such a search without significant coding.  You should update your question to clarify that you want to find the same two functions called with the same parameter, _within the same block_, at least if that's what you really mean.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question. "with the same argument being passed" does it mean value inside the argument? Why does sin(x) first case qualify as match and another case is not a match?